# What would happen if I bind a function which requests more than 1 parameter with a UIButton and target it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, cpu-registers

I am studying how to develop applications in iOS, and try to understand the basic UI and the whole runtime thing of objective-c recently, and this question appeared when I accidentally add a target action which requests 3 parameters to a single button: the first parameter is button(the sender, absolutely), but the second and the third parameter is an `UITouchesEvent`.

[image: my test code and registers]

when I get to the registers, I found that `x1` register is the button, but `x3` to `x5` is the `UITouchesEvent`. I believe that's how the 2nd and 3rd parameter came from, but why? why this `UITouchesEvent` would be one of the parameters?
what's the rule behind this?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's docs:

> **action**
>
> A selector identifying the action method to be called. You may specify a selector whose signature matches any of the signatures in [Listing 1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol?language=objc#1943645). This parameter must not be nil.

Following the link to Listing 1:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething;
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

So, trying to use a selector for a method with other parameters would likely be considered "undefined" ... and possibly get flagged as "non-public API" usage.

Comment: +1, explains the second argument. What you get after the second argument is definitely undefined, but it's not "non-public API" usage; you won't get a rejection because of this, except if your app crashes when you try to access such an argument as a pointer/object (it may contain arbitrary garbage values).

Comment: Thanks! I also found that apple doc yesterday, and it's more clear with your explanation.